# Spotfire JQuery: Data Function updates document property, JQuery on change Event not called

Tags: javascript, jquery, spotfire

I have a data function that updates a document property. The property is a string of HTML code. The string is an HTML mockup of an unordered list. When ever the data function updates the document property, my javascript code to take that document property's value and put it into a div's html isn't fired. The on change function that does that process is only fired when I click the input box and put an extra space or something...

In the end I want to hide the input box and just display the div containing the document property formatted as html.

( I'm using an input box instead of a label since the javascript worked better for me)

This is what I want...

1. datafunction runs and updates document property
2. javascript realizes the document property has changed and runs (without user interacting with the document property's field)

here is my code...

HTML/CSS

```
<style>
ul li {
  color: black; 
  list-style: none; 
  font-size: 1.5em;
  padding: 5px 0px;
}

ul li::before {
  color: rgb(227,114,34);  
  content: "\2022"; 
  font-size: 1.5em; 
  padding-right: 1.1225em; 

  position: relative;
  top: 0em; 
}
</style>
<DIV id="analysis"><SpotfireControl id="03f5066b000f41babdcb3807ec8fca41" /> 
</DIV>
<DIV id="preview"></DIV>
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
$("#analysis input").bind('input propertychange',livePreview);
$("#analysis input").on('change',livePreview);

function livePreview(){
    $("#preview").html($("#analysis input").val())
}
```

here is an example of the document property value

```
<ul><li>Line 1</li><li>Line 2</li><ul><li>Line 3 indented</li><li>Line 4 indented</li></ul><li>line 5</li><li>line 6</li></ul>
```

Comment: Have you tried this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver

Comment: I ended up using an Iron Python Script to do what I was wanting to do rather than a datafunction. In the script I set the HTML to the Text area in the script rather than having javascript do it.